# Netgear WNDR3700 WiFi-n not giving 40 MBps

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I have a Netgear WNDR 3700 v3 WiFi router. The router is capable of A/b/g/n and the Internet connection is 40MBps

When I connect over the ethernet cable and run speedtest, I get the full 40MBps connectivity. But over WiFi, both on the 2.4GHz and 5GHz, I never get more than 25-28MBps.

The router is configured with WPA2-PSK for both the bands and they each have their own SSIDs.

Is it possible to achieve the full 40MBps of Internet connectivity over Wifi? If yes, what do I change in the router configuration? I'll provide any additional information needed on the current configuration.

Thanks in advance

Edit:
Looking at the linked post (Thanks @DavidPostill), adding additional information: The WiFi security is set to WPA2-PSK (AES). I've just enabled QoS WMM on. That seems to have fixed the issue for 11n. For the 2.4 GHz channel, it has actually reduced speed

Comment: Are you sure the device you’re testing with can do 11n? Because those speeds look very 11g/a to me.

Comment: @DavidPostill No it is not the same. I'm getting a slower speed over WiFi that the theoretical/advertised speed for that router. I only mentioned the wired speeds to provide information that the Internet connection does provide the full 40MBps bandwidth promised by the ISP

Comment: @DanielB Yes. I have a retina macbook pro which is WiFi ac compatible and also supports 11n (https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs-retina/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to enable QoS WMM and ensure that the encryption/security option used is WPA2-PSK with AES. I'm not getting symmetric ~40MBps connections

ETA: Additional notes: I get ~30 MBps Internet speeds on 2.4 GHz and ~40 MBps on 5GHz (Assuming both on the 11n channel)